# Passing delegates across assemblies

Tags: c#, delegates, .net-assembly, appdomain

I created a wrapper for an existing project that currently only officially supports Lua for server-side coding, the server is coded in C# so it wasn't a real issue to use reflection to access the methods provided in Lua.
I'm loading "scripts" into a new AppDomain, which works just fine, however, as soon as I'm passing a delegate (delegates are used as event handlers by the server code, passed through one of the methods), the host domain attempts to load the script's assembly, which defeats the original purpose of separating the scripts from the host domain so they could be unloaded.
if I do provide the host domain with the assembly, everything works fine, until I edit the code and add/remove/modify the delegates, which then breaks every reference to the calling methods since it relies on an older copy of the assembly, as I'm loading it from a byte array so the assembly file could be modified at run time.

How can I pass delegates without having to load the assembly passing them into the host AppDomain so the scripts could remain truly isolated from the hosting AppDomain and be unloaded/loaded at will?

EDIT: Using the classes SeparateAppDomain and MefLoader from the Plugin framework project on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/831823/Plugin-framework I load scripts like so:

Load() on the hosting domain

```
MefLoader mefLoader = SeparateAppDomain.CreateInstance<MefLoader>(path, path);
List<IServerScript> scripts = mefLoader.Load<IServerScript>();
foreach (IServerScript script in scripts)
{
    ServerScript ss = ((ServerScript)script);

    ss.CreateProxy(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
}
```

In the ServerScript class (which is loaded on the new AppDomain by the MefLoader class)

```
private Wrapper w = null;
internal void CreateProxy(AppDomain HostDomain)
{
    Type wrappertype = typeof(Wrapper);
    w = (Wrapper)HostDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(wrappertype.Assembly.FullName, wrappertype.FullName, false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, null);
}
```

`w` is the way back to the hosting domain, which handles everything regarding reflection to the server assembly.

The issue is reproduced like so:

In ServerScript

```
public void Test(Delegate d)
{
    if (w != null) w.Test(d);
}
```

In any class inheriting ServerScript that would be loaded by MefLoader

```
Test(new Action(() => { });
```

In Wrapper

```
public void Test(Delegate d)
{
}
```

The hosting domain does not attempt to load the script assembly until the call `w.Test(d)` is made in ServerScript.

EDIT 2: After further tests, the cause isn't the separate appdomains, but the separate assemblies, unless I pass a delegate that's defined in the wrapper assembly I end up with the issue described above, this is more than likely why the wrapper attempts to load the script assembly, is there any way I could pass delegates (would often be an Action<> with a varying amount of parameters depending on the use case) from the script assembly to the wrapper assembly without loading the script assembly into the wrapper's domain?

Comment: can you paste some code demonstrating how you work with appdomain?

Comment: @LeiYang see edit